# How to animate a custom graphic component property

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, animation, flex4.5, mxml

I created a custom timer component, which basically renders a circle sector, with a default start angle (0) and an end angle:

```
public class Arc extends FilledElement
{
    private var _endAngle:Number = 0;

    public function Arc()
    {
    }

    public function get endAngle():Number
    {
        return _endAngle;
    }

    public function set endAngle(value:Number):void
    {
        if (_endAngle == value)
            return;

        _endAngle = value;
        invalidateDisplayList();
    }

    // left out the rendering logic, for clarity
}
```

Works fine and dandy so far. This is the code which renders the sector:

```
<org:Arc id="arc"
     endAngle="135">
    <org:fill>
        <s:SolidColor color="#FFFF00" />
    </org:fill>
</org:Arc>
```

However, I want to animate the endAngle property. This is the MXML code which aims to achieve this:

```
<s:Animate id="effect"
       duration="2000"
       target="arc">
    <s:SimpleMotionPath property="endAngle"
            valueFrom="90"
            valueTo="180" />
</s:Animate>
```

The problem is then when I play the effect, I get this error:
**Error: Property endAngle is not a property or a style on object arc: TypeError: Error #1006: value is not a function..**

Has anyone else encountered this problem, or better yet, does anyone know what I did wrong and how to fix this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Animate#target` property does not evaluate string values to object ID's. You have to bind the target element instead (or it will try to find the property `endAngle` on the String `"arc"`, which will throw the error you're getting):

```
<s:Animate id="effect" duration="2000" target="{arc}">
    <s:SimpleMotionPath property="endAngle" valueFrom="90" valueTo="180" />
</s:Animate>
```

Note the only difference between your version and mine is the curly braces {}